# How to install any linux distro as a main & only OS on my HP Laptop?

Tags: linux, manjaro

I had used Ubuntu in WSL2 for 3-4 days, also tried to use Kali Linux on WSL2, but due to network manager problems I abandoned my idea. Yesterday I was trying to dual boot Pop OS with Windows 10 but due to a wrong partition configuration (I have GPT mode but did in MBR) I was unable to do this. I also tried to do in GPT mode. It was not showing in the boot menu. My friend told me, that Microsoft destroys grub boot loader when we dual-booting with linux distro.

Now, I have decided to use a Manjaro as my main and only OS on my machine. How can I do this? Will I face any problem like grub boot? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: All you need to do is to install it and when choosing partitioning, you can delete everything and then install Manjaro. Have you actually tried to install it?

Comment: Gpt is drive partitioning, not boot mode. But Windows does require gpt partitioning for UEFI boot. If UEFI hardware best to use gpt and UEFI boot for all systems. Windows does not delete Linux UEFI boot entries. But some UEFI only recognize Linux boot entry if you go into UEFI settings (not UEFI boot) and change boot order.

Comment: I don't understand the "problem like grub boot" part. Grub2 is the standard bootloader of most Linux distros. What do you mean with Grub2 booting being a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like someone said in a comment, you can partition the whole disk during installation and give it all to your Linux distribution.

To answer your dual boot question, if you install Windows (or Mac OS) before installing Linux you should be fine (unless the big OSes have started overwriting the boot record during software updates).